# C - CreateProcess returning data from child process

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2012

I've done some research looking for the best method for retrieving data from a process created by CreateProcess(), but unfortunately, I have not had much luck. If anyone can point me in the proper direction that would be much appreciated.

I have a very basic console application in C. Here is the source,

```
int main() {
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    char CommandLine[1024] = "\"\" \"501 Willow\" \"\" \"Greenville\" \"AL\" \"36037\"";
    memset (&si, 0, sizeof(si));
    memset (&pi, 0, sizeof(pi));
    GetStartupInfo(&si);
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;

    if (CreateProcess (("C:\\pathTO\\ValidateRDI.exe"), CommandLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi) != 0) {
        printf("Separate Process created\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Separate Process not created. Error occurred\n");
    }

    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

    return 0;
}
```

The CreateProcess runs another C console application that calls a DLL like so,

```
typedef void (CALLBACK* LPFNDLLFUNC1)(char*,char*,char*,char*,char*,char*,char*,char*,char*,char*,char*);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    HMODULE hDLL;
    LPFNDLLFUNC1 lpfnDllFunc; 
    char name[35+1] = "";
    char addr1[35+1] = "";
    char addr2[35+1] = "";
    char city[20+1] = "";
    char state[2+1] = "";
    char zip[10+1] = "";
    char rdi[1+1] = "";
    char returnCode[2+1] = "";
    char returnText[101] = "";
    char errorWarningCode[2+1] = "";
    char errorWarningText[100+1] = "";
    sprintf(name, argv[0]);
    sprintf(addr1, argv[1]);
    sprintf(addr2, argv[2]);
    sprintf(city, argv[3]);
    sprintf(state, argv[4]);
    sprintf(zip, argv[5]);

    hDLL = LoadLibraryA((LPCSTR)"ValidateRDI.dll");
    if (hDLL != NULL)
    {
        lpfnDllFunc = (LPFNDLLFUNC1)GetProcAddress(hDLL,"ValidateAddress");
        if(lpfnDllFunc)
        {
            lpfnDllFunc(name,addr1,addr2,city,state,zip,rdi,returnCode,returnText,errorWarningCode,errorWarningText);
        }
        // free library
        FreeLibrary(hDLL);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Just for a heads up, I removed some error checking to slim down the code. **How would I pass back the following values (or share the variables) to the console application that calls CreateProcess():**

- name
- addr1
- addr2
- city
- state
- zip
- rdi
- returnCode
- returnText
- errorWarningCode
- errorWarningText

Any and all help is appreciated. I've thought of writing the values to a file and then accessing the data once  *WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );* returns, but there must be a more efficient/better method.

Comment: `argv[0]` is not what you think it is, the first argument (name) is `argv[1]`, `argv[0]` is the name of the program.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I saw that somewhere online and thought the same thing, but it's actually passing the correct value. I'll keep an eye on it as I test though and will be weary. I may be overlooking something. I appreciate the time!

Comment: you could setup a 'named pipe'  Have the child process write to the pipe, have the parent process read from the pipe

Comment: you could setup a shared memory that both processes can access

Comment: this kind of statement is a security problem.  `sprintf(name, argv[0]);`  suggest using: `sprintf( name, "%35s", argv[0] );`   Similar considerations exist for the other fields

Comment: @user3629249 I appreciate the suggestions and tips. If you list your comments as an answer, I'll accept it! Double points if you can link a tutorial on setting up a named pipe as a rookie. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3629249 It seems like a lot of the stuff out there (header files) require a linux environment.